# How to hide google ads in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my project , i have implemented Google-Mobile-Ads SDK. I have followed all the steps with are written in the google site. I am able to access the google ad in all my view controllers as i have coded it in my AppDelegate.

Now , i want it to hide it from the first view controller (like we can hide navigationbar), how to implement this ?

In have coded this for google ads in AppDelegate`s DidFinishLaunchingMethod:-

```
 bannerView=[[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.window.frame.size.height-50, self.window.frame.size.width, 50)];
[self.window addSubview:bannerView];

bannerView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-8809802355107737/4999307809";
bannerView.rootViewController = self.window.rootViewController;
bannerView.delegate=self;
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
request.testDevices = @[ @"eba07768136b615eee7c1f8acde25c1b",kGADSimulatorID ];
[bannerView loadRequest:request];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```

---

I have this method also in appDelegate class :-

```
 - (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)view;
  {
  if (container.view.frame.size.height==self.window.frame.size.height-50) {

   }
else
{
CGRect navFrame = container.view.frame;
navFrame.size.height -= 50;
container.view.frame = navFrame;
}
NSLog(@"asdhaskda");
  }
```

Comment: `bannerView.hidden`?

Comment: please declare you bannerview object in  .h file @Ammy

Comment: in .h file of appDelegate ?? or in viewController where i want to hide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in firstViewController:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"HIDEBANNER" object:nil];
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SHOWBANNER" object:nil];
}
```

In AppDelegate.m file, in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(hideBanner) name:@"HIDEBANNER" object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(showBanner) name:@"SHOWBANNER" object:nil];
```

Also implement those 2 functions. I'm not sure what exactly must be in those functions. Maybe something like this:

```
 -(void)showBanner{
    [bannerView setHidden:NO];
    //this is from your code
if (container.view.frame.size.height==self.window.frame.size.height-50) {

   }
else
{
CGRect navFrame = container.view.frame;
navFrame.size.height -= 50;
container.view.frame = navFrame;
}
}

-(void)hideBanner{
    [bannerView setHidden:YES];
    CGRect navFrame = container.view.frame;
    navFrame.size.height = self.window.frame.size.height;
    container.view.frame = navFrame;
}
```

Comment: I have change the  viewControllers frame  , WOrking fine @adBODKAt

Answer (score 1):

There are many methods to do that. You can use, for example, NSNotificationCenter.

In your AppDelegate.m file in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(hideBanner) name:@"HIDEBANNER" object:nil];
```

Also in AppDelegate.m add the following function:

```
-(void)hideBanner{
    [bannerView setHidden:YES];
}
```

And somewhere in you project, when you need to hide banner just call this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"HIDEBANNER" object:nil];
```

Comment: @ adBODKAt - Thanks it works , ad hides but now a black space is appearing the place of add . What to do ?

Comment: I'm not sure. Looks like it resize main view. Try in your root view resize it subview when hiding banner. Something like this: CGRect r = self.view.frame; r.size.height = r.size.height + 50; r.origin.y = 0; [self.view setFrame:r];

Comment: I have done that , All is working fine , But it gets hidden in all viewControllers now ? @ adBODKAt

Comment: Sorry, missed this part about first view controller. Well, my code about NotificationCenter not needed. Try to make size of your first view controller equal to screen. For example in viewWillAppear function. Also, in adViewDidReceiveAd check what view on screen, and don't resize, if it's your first view.

Comment: Sorry , Not able to implement it,  Can you guide me how ? @ adBODKAt

Comment: Or you can use Notifications. In first view controller, in viewWillAppear send notification to hide banner and resize view controller to it's normal size, and on viewDidDisappear send notification to show banner and resize view controller to smaller size.

Comment: Please Give me some example code, not able to implement it @ adBODKAt

Answer (score 0):

AdMob Integration Full Code.

```
AppDelegate.h 
// Write This Code in AppDelegate.h File Start

@import GoogleMobileAds;

#pragma mark - Admob
@property (strong, nonatomic) GADBannerView  *bannerView;

-(void)loadAdmob:(UIViewController *)vc;
// End

AppDelegate.m
```

// Write This Code in AppDelegate.m File Start

#pragma mark - Admob Methods
   -(void)loadAdmob:(UIViewController *)vc{

```
self.bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, vc.view.frame.size.height-kBannerHeight, vc.view.frame.size.width, kBannerHeight)];

[vc.view addSubview:self.bannerView];
self.bannerView.hidden = YES;

//### Load Banner Ad view #####
// Replace this ad unit ID with your own ad unit ID.
self.bannerView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-####";  // Botttom banner

self.bannerView.rootViewController = vc;

GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
// Requests test ads on devices you specify. Your test device ID is printed to the console when
// an ad request is made.

#ifdef DEBUG
   request.testDevices = @[kGADSimulatorID]; 
//[Note: Comment this line for release build]
#endif

     [self.bannerView loadRequest:request];
}
```

// Add this code in Viewcontroller.m file 
       [APP_DELEGATE loadAdmob:self];

// Add this line in PrefixHeader.pch
  #define APP_DELEGATE (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication   sharedApplication] delegate]
  #define kBannerHeight (IS_IPAD ? 65.0 : 49.0)

Comment: @Ammy - May i know on which place or which view controller you want  to hide because i used today in my code and am able to hide it.

Comment: I want to implement it in ViewController.m and i have declared the bannerView in AppDelegate.h @Mahesh Sonaiya

Comment: Please check my full code as i have modified my answer and let me know if you need any help.

Comment: Not able to use this code :--- [APP_DELEGATE loadAdmob:self]; @ Mahesh Sonaiya

Comment: Hi,Read this comment Add this line in PrefixHeader.pch

Comment: @ Mahesh Sonaiya - Not working bro , not able to show ads in bottom with  your code

Comment: @ Mahesh - kBannerHeight is not working , so i m giving any custom hieght

Comment: @Ammy - Please add this code in PrefixHeader.ch File                        #define kBannerHeight (IS_IPAD ? 65.0 : 49.0)

Comment: i have given height manually , Still there is some error, Not able to view banner

Comment: Have you added your device id in request.testDevices array?

Comment: Yes , i have added both id`s

Comment: in my case, it's working with same code. can you provide me code?

Comment: @ Mahesh - Not able to view ads , implemented all which u stated above